# C# ownerdrawn TreeView with custom expand area

Tags: c#, treeview, expand, ownerdrawn

I am using a TreeView with DrawMode = OwnerDrawAll. So I am supposed to be able to draw the nodes anyway I like in the DrawNode event I guess.

However, the region where the minus/plus for expansion/collapse *would have been*, still works. I want to paint a plus/minus image somewhere else, but it seems I am forced to paint it in the small predefined area, because Windows uses that area in any case.

My question: How can I define my own region responsible for expand/collapse? Or at least get rid of the predefined area, so that nothing happens when the user clicks in it?

Comment: `treeView1.ShowPlusMinus = false;`

Comment: @LarsTech: Wow, so simple. Thank you very much. Please post this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try turning off the property that controls that:

```
treeView1.ShowPlusMinus = false;
```